# Calculating $E(\frac{X_1}{X_2+1})$

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables and have density function $P[X_1=k]=P[X_2=k]=pq^k , k=0,1,2,...$ how can we calculate $E\left(\frac{X_1}{X_2+1}\right)?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By independence, we have
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{E}(\frac{X_1}{X_2 + 1})
~=~\mathsf{E}(X_1)\cdot\mathsf{E}(\frac{1}{X_2 + 1})
\end{align}
Since $X_1$, $X_2$ follow geometric distribution, we have
$$
\mathsf{E}(X_1) = \frac{q}{p}
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{E}(\frac{1}{X_2 + 1}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k + 1}\cdot pq^k = \frac{p}{q}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}q^{k+1} = \frac{p}{q}\cdot (-\log(1 - q))
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathsf{E}(\frac{X_1}{X_2 + 1}) = \frac{q}{p} \cdot \frac{p}{q} \cdot (-\log(1 - q)) = -\log(1-q)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $E(\frac{X_1}{X_2+1}) = E(X_1)E(\frac{1}{X_2+1}),$ because of independence.